# Grounding & USB-C To HDMI Adapter

Tags: usb, ground, grounding, adapter, ground-loop

I've a MacBook that comes with a 2-prong 30 watt USB-C charger. Since it's a 2-prong charger, there's no ground terminal.

Now, suppose I connect this MacBook to an external monitor, and the external monitor itself is connected to wall via a 3-prong power adapter (thus the external monitor's circuitry is connected to ground), does this mean that technically even my MacBook is grounded via USB-C to HDMI Adapter to the ground path of that external monitor?